# Using C# MongoDB to convert Int to String?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using C# `MongoDb.Driver`(2.10)  to get a document from a collection :

```
MongoClient dbClient = new 
MongoClient("mongodb://***");
IMongoDatabase db = dbClient.GetDatabase("***");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("***");
Console.WriteLine( collection.Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty).First());
```

This does work and emits this :

[image]

So everything is OK.

But now I want to try to filter where `lockPolicyId.ToString()=="1"` .(*As a string , not as a number*)

So I've tried :

```
var filter= Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Where(a=>a["lockPolicyId"].AsString=="1");
var t=collection.Find( filter ).First() ;
Console.Writeline(t);
```

Which shows this error :

> The operands for operator 'Equal' do not match the parameters of
>   method 'op_Equality'.

I've also tried:

```
 var filter= Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Where(a=>a["lockPolicyId"].ToString()=="1");
```

And got this error:

> {document}{lockPolicyId}.ToString() is not supported.

Now, I do understand why it's happening ( Int and not String).

But still

**Question:**

How can I filter by the ToString value?

In other words, to make this line works:

```
Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Where(a=>a["lockPolicyId"].AsString=="1")
```

Comment: The column must be another class.  When you type the period what options are you given?

Comment: @jdweng https://i.imgur.com/X3xQDqE.jpg

Comment: It is a MongoDB object.  Those selections are not a standard  Net Library type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not possible.

MongoDB C# driver interprets `a=>a["lockPolicyId"]==1` as `{lockPolicyId: {"$eq" : "1"}}`.

When you try `a=>a["lockPolicyId"].AsString=="1"`, it can't be interpreted into MongoDB syntax... (such query `{{$toString:"lockPolicyId"} : "1"}` is invalid)

---

MongoDB `.find` method has exception with `$where` operator:

```
db.collection.find({"$where": "this.lockPolicyId.toString() == '1'"})
```

But you need to write such queries manually (can't be written by `Predicate` interface). **Note:** It's very slow

MongoDB offers `aggregate` command to perform unusual queries. You need to define query pipeline. If you use `$toString` operator in the 1st stage and then apply matching criteria in the 2nd one, it will work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$addFields:{
        lockPolicyId : {$toString:"$lockPolicyId"}
    }},
    {$match:{
        lockPolicyId : "1"
    }}
])
```

Comment: So what is AsString is there for ?